# If points (0,0), (1,0), and (x,y) are the vertices of a right triangle, determine any equations that x and/or y must satisfy

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, triangles

I know that the x can be 0, 0.5, 1 and while x is 0 or 1 y can be anything be when x is 0.5 y is 0.5 as well, but I can't find the equation that satisfies all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not one equation.  There are two lines that $(x,y)$ can be on a circle.  You should find an equation for each line and the circle.  There is a way to combine the equations, but it obscures what is going on a little.

The lines are $x=0$ and $x=1$.  The circle is centered at $(\frac 12,0)$ with radius $\frac 12$, so is $(x-\frac 12)^2+y^2=\frac 14$  We can combine all that into
$$x(x-1)\left[\left(x-\frac 12\right)^2+y^2-\frac 14\right]=0$$

Comment: Indeed. In fact, it's not hard to show that for any two distinct points in the plane, the set of points which make the triplet a right triangle is a reducible variety, so a single equation isn't possible.

Comment: What if $(x,y)$ lies on the circle with diameter joining the two points? Then the three points form a right triangle by [Thales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27s_theorem).

Comment: $(x,y)$ can be on two lines and a circle, not on 2 lines and 2 points.

Comment: @JairTaylor:  good point.  I had only gotten two of the points of the circle.  Updated.

Comment: @DonThousand Isn't union of varieties the set of zeros corresponding to product of (irreducible) polynomials? Then reducible can be given by a single equation.

Comment: Technically the equation also gives the points $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$, which give degenerate triangles.

Comment: @N.S. Depends on terminology. I use the term variety in a way that some use the term algebraic set. So, when I say reducible variety, I mean algebraic set that isn't a variety by another common terminology.

Comment: @DonThousand I am a bit confused, the union of zeroes of polynomials, which this is what this is, can always be described by a single equation: the equation given by the product of polynomials. You are trying to argue that this is not the case in this situation, so I must be missing something.

Comment: @N.S. I think your understanding of varieties is not correct. Varieties need not always be defined by a single equation. A point unioned with a line is a variety. Is there an equation defining both? (Again, I'm a math noob, so correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: @DonThousand The answer is actually yes if you work over the real numbers but I think you are right if you work over algebraically closed fields. Note that over $\mathbb R$ you can alwasy write the variety given by $P_1 \wedge P_2 \wedge .... \wedge P_n$ as $P_1^2+....+P_n^2=0$. Anyhow, in this case, the set is the union of varieties, each given by a single equation.

Comment: @N.S. I don't think it's just about algebraically closed fields, I just think that the real numbers are an exception.

Comment: @N.S. Because varieties over reals are just points.

Comment: @DonThousand $x^2+y^2=1$.

Comment: @N.S. That's $\mathbb R^2$, not $\mathbb R$. There are quite a few different types of varieties over $\mathbb R^2$, including weird ones like $\mathbb R\times\{0\}\setminus\{(0,0\}$

Comment: @DonThousand That's a variety in $\mathbb R^2$ OVER $\mathbb R$, anyhow, if you want to call it a variety over $\mathbb R^2$, read my previous comment as: Over $\mathbb R^2$ you can alwasy write the variety given by $P_1 \wedge P_2 \wedge .... \wedge P_n$ as $P_1^2+....+P_n^2=0$. This has nothing to do with the fact that varieties in $\mathbb R$ are just points.

Comment: @N.S. Ok, then how would you express $\mathbb R\times\{0\}\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ as a sum of squares?

Answer (score 0):

For $A(0,0);B(1,0);C(x,y)$

If $m_{AB}$ is the gradient of $AB$

We exactly one of the following to be $-1$

$m_{AB}\cdot m_{BC}$

$m_{AB}\cdot m_{CA}$

$m_{BC}\cdot m_{CA}$

Answer (score 0):

By Pytagora's theorem, the triangle is right exactly when one of the following equations holds
$$x^2+y^2=1+(x-1)^2+y^2 \Leftrightarrow 1-x =0  \mbox{ or }\\
x^2+y^2+1=(x-1)^2+y^2 \Leftrightarrow x =0  \mbox{ or }\\
x^2+y^2+(x-1)^2+y2=1 \Leftrightarrow x^2-x+y^2=0 $$

Therefore, the triangle is right exactly when
$$(1-x) \cdot x \cdot \left(  x^2-x+y^2 \right) =0$$

Of course, as some of the comments point out, you need to know that $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$ and $(x,y) \neq (1,1)$, as these are the solutions which do lead to "degenerate" right triangles.

Answer (score 0):

There are three possibilities for which side of the triangle $\vec{(0,0),(1,1)}$ is.

The first two are trivial, they have $x=0$ or $x=1$ with $y\neq0$.

The third is when the line is the hypotenuse.
[image]
Observe the diagram. I've rotated the triangle, $(0,0)$ is at the angle marked $theta$, $(1,1)$ is at the other non-right angle. $S=\sin\theta, C=\cos\theta$ for reference.

We use the Inverse Pythagorean Theorem, $$\frac{1}{h^2}=\frac{1}{S^2}+\frac{1}{C^2}$$
Which yields $$\frac{1}{h^2}=\frac{S^2+C^2}{(SC)^2}\to h=SC\because S^2+C^2=1$$

Then we find $t$ using the regular Pythagorean Theorem, $$t^2=C^2-(SC)^2\to t^2=C^2(1-S^2)=C^4\to t=C^2\implies 1-t=S^2$$

Hence the third triangle looks like the below, we have:
$$x=\cos^2\theta$$
$$y=\cos\theta\sin\theta$$
[image]